# Can non-UI threads display to the screen?

Tags: .net, multithreading, ui-thread

Is only the UI-thread able to display to the screen, or can other threads do this as well?

Comment: FYI: You can have more than one UI thread in a process.

Comment: @Brian: Where can I learn about this? I didn't know there was more than one UI thread . . .

Comment: .NET restricts access to GUI controls to the STA thread that created them. You can create other STA threads with their own set of controls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you can only access to UI directly from the UI thread but you can marshal the results from other threads, such as using the Control.Invoke or control.BegineInvoke/EndInvoke

Check [this](http://dougzuck.com/c-ui-threading-example) out

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `BeginInvoke()` member of all GUI controls to change the values of their properties from background threads.
If you are using a backgroundworker you could use the `ReportProgress` event, which is even easier.

Answer (score 0):

also Depends if you are using WinForms or WPF, in Winforms you use Control.Invoke and in WPF you use Dispatcher class. WPF has more sophisticated thread UI dispatcher